# vSphere 5 and Powerpath/VE?

Tags: storage-area-network, vmware-vsphere, emc, powerpath

I am in the process of setting up our vSphere 5 environment.  With previous version of vSphere I have used the native pathing with VMware but I now want to investigate Powerpath/VE since it now works for v5.  Has anyone swapped over to using Powerpath on your hosts and if so have you seen any performance hits/increases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not migrated, however my EMC rep told me that the biggest benefit is not performance, but standardization with the physical servers running powerpath. VMWare is extremely good about storage multi-pathing with the native tools, and I can't see much of an opportunity to improve that.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I think for now I will continue to use the VMware native pathing.